# Accessing ADF components in one application from another application

Tags: oracle-adf

I do have some ADF BC components deployed in an ear . I want to access those from another ear. Is that possible ?

eg : I do have a TestAM ( application module ) defined in application ( A.ear) and I wan to access TestAM from a servlet in another application ( B.ear )

Thanks
Jijoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you expose the TestAM as an EJB then you can call it remotely.
Also possible to wrap it as a web service and call that way.

Look at Service Interface and EJB Session Bean tabs on the AM in JDev.